# Which Bitcoin miners allow one to use paths in URLs?

Tags: mining-pools, json-rpc, server, mining-software

I've recently been experimenting with implementing a pool and testing it against GUIminer. To my surprise, it was not able to handle paths in URL of the pool, only subdomains. For example, calling:

```
http://tpbitpool.appspot.com
```

on port 80 gives a proper response of

```
{'message': 'Method not found', 'code': -32601, 'data': 'The called method was not found on the server'}
```

But calling

```
http://tpbitpool.appspot.com/anything
```

Or even

```
http://tpbitpool.appspot.com/
```

Despite being able to be handled by the server, gives an error of

```
"Problems communicating with bitcoin RPC"
```

Testing the same URLs with Python's jsonrpc gives correct results.

Is there any reason why a miner would behave in this way? Is there a list of mining software that behave similarly?

(note, the above URL should be up for some time for testing purposes, but reachable only via http and https ports)

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you end the URL with a '/', just like you did with the first one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hmm, actually, yes, I accidentally copied the address from my browser rather than GUIminer, fixing that now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DiabloMiner allows both URLs and non-URLs. -l http://user:pass@host:port/ is the same as -u user -p password -o host -r port. URLs may contain paths.